# Content type - manage display based on roles?

Tags: entities, nodes

Is there a way to define a custom display setting under Manage Display on a content type? I want to hide certain fields (when viewing, not editing) from non-authenticated users. I know I can do this with a custom .tpl file; just wondering if there's another way (without additional modules.)

Comment: You'll need to implement _some_ sort of field permissions for this, and rather than reinvent the wheel I can't recommend [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions/) strongly enough. If you're dead set against adding another module, have a look at the code in that one to see how it handles such things. The manage display page doesn't even need to come into it...the fields that anonymous users don't have access to simply won't show up when they view the entity page

Comment: Yeah, I know about Field Permissions; I just wondered if there was a way to create a new custom display choice.

Comment: I've added an answer for how to do that (was too long for a comment), I'm not quite sure how you'll integrate that with your permission requirements but hopefully it'll get you started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as implementing a new view mode yourself goes it's pretty easy, without any contrib modules.

You can implement [`hook_entity_info_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7) to add a custom view mode to any entity. For example this code adds a new view mode called "Test View" to the node entity type:

```
function MYMODULE_entity_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['node']['view modes']['test_view'] = array(
    'label' => 'Test View',
    'custom settings' => TRUE
  );
}
```

After a cache clear that view mode will appear in all the places you'd expect (manage display, views, etc.)